# Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have implemented Google Drive functionality for file management. It's working fine in local system but whenever I hosted it on my server it throws the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied. 


 string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" }; 


 UserCredential credential =    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets {
                ClientId = "clientId", ClientSecret = "clientSecret" }, 
                scopes, "test2", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Google.Apis.Auth")).Result;
```

I alternatively, provide another folder as a relative path, and the code hangs.

Comment: you need to show the code that throws the exception

Answer (score 0):

The Google .Net client library uses `FileDatastore` that stores the credentials in `%AppData%` directory by default. When the following code authenticates:

> new FileDataStore("Google.Apis.Auth")

A folder will be created in the `%AppData%` directory on the machine executing the code. When you run your application under what ever user it is you are running you don't apparently have access to the `%AppData%` directory.